# Running DAG in Loop

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I want to run Airflow DAG in a continuous loop. Below is the dependency of my DAG:

create_dummy_start >> task1 >> task2 >> task3 >> create_dummy_end >> task_email_notify

The requirement is as soon as the flow reaches the create_dummy_end, the flow should re-iterate back to first task i.e. create_dummy_start.

I have tried re-triggering the DAG using below code:

```
`create_dummy_end = TriggerDagRunOperator(
    task_id='End_Task',
    trigger_dag_id=dag.dag_id,
    dag=dag
)`
```

This will re-trigger the DAG but previous instance of DAG also keeps running, and hence it starts multiple instances parallelly which does not suffice the requirement.

I am new to Airflow, any inputs would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

By definition DAG is "Acyclic" (Directed Acyclic Graph) - there are no cycles.

Airflow - in general - works on "schedule" rather than "continuously" and while you can try to (as you did) trigger a new dag manually, this will always be "another dag run". There is no way to get Airflow in a continuous loop like that within a single DAG run.

You can use other tools for such purpose (which is much closer to streaming rather than Airflow's Batch processing). For example you can use Apache Beam for that - it seems to better fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jarek. Is there any way to mark the DAG as success within my code, so that I can mark previous execution as success before triggering the DAG again. I am sorry if this seems to be a silly question but I am little new to airflow.

Comment: You could just set `wait_for_completion` parameter to false. That would allow your first DAG to finish even if the triggered one is still running. But again, I'd see that as anti-pattern and it will bite you sooner or later IMHO.